# Tic-Tac-Toe Turbo C

Tags: turbo-c++

Please I'm trying to make a simple game of tic-tac-toe but I kept getting an error. It says Error Syntax and while statement if missing ) . I would be happy if you someone could help 'cause I just started studying how to code. Here's the code btw.

```
#include<stdio.>
char sqr [3][3]
main()
{
char again;
int moveCntr, winFlag;
while (1 = = 1)
{
initliz();
sqr[1][1] = 'X';
disbord();
getmove();
makemove();
moveCntr = 3;

while(1 = = 1)
{
disbord();
getmove();
moveCntr = moveCntr + 1;

winFlag = Checkwin ('0');
if(winFlag = = 1)
{
dispbord();
printf("Congratulations!! You win.\n");
break();
}
else
{
makemove();

winFlag = checkwin ('X');
if(winFlag = = 1)
{
dispbord();
printf("I win.\n");
break;
}
}
moveCntr = moveCntr + 1;
if(moveCntr = = 9)
{
dispbord();
printf("It's a draw. Good game.\n");
}
else
{
continue;
}
}
printf("\nDo you want to play again (Y/N)?");
scanf("\n%c" ,&again);

if(again = = 'Y' || again = = 'y')
{
continue;
}
else
{
break;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When posting question about build errors, please include the actual errors in the body of the question, unedited, in full and complete. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A small hint for you though: The operator to compare for equality is `==` and not `= =`.

Comment: Noted. I'll do it next time I post. Thanks for the tip.